# RSA Public Key of WSO2carbon

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, json-web-token

I am generating JWT token from WSOAM which is then passed as a header to API. I have my API created in nodejs and I am using **jsonwebtoken** plugin to verify and decode the JWT.

I am unable to find RSA Public key of Wso2carbon to verify/decode the token.

Please help me as how to generate the RSA Public key or where should I find this key ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All WSO2 products use the default public/private key pairs installed into [wso2carbon.jks keystore](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Keystores) file found in `<WSO2_AM>/repository/resources/security` directory. It's advised to use your own keystore instead of this default keystore shipped with all WSO2 products.

> It is recommended to replace this default keystore with a new keystore
>   that has self-signed or CA signed certificates when the products are
>   deployed in production environments. This is because wso2carbon.jks is
>   available with open source WSO2 products, which means anyone can have
>   access to the private key of the default keystore.

If you are going to use the default private/public keys, use the following command to extract the key.

```
keytool -export -keystore <WSO2_AM>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks -alias wso2carbon -file Example.cer
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the public key used to sign the jwt token by invoking the GET https://<identity_server_url>/oauth2/jwks endpoint (be careful to choose the main domain or the tenant domain, i.e. https://<identity_server_url>/t/<tenant_name>/oauth2/jwks).
Then I converted it to PEM format using a site like this: https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp

hope this helps.